# How to get Company names in Product filter function in Django?

Tags: python, django, filter, model

I would like to get a JSON dict that contains all product names including corresponding company names (see 'Output I want' section). My search/filter function returns numbers as companies, which is wrong (see 'Output I have' section). Thanks!

**Product model**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Company model**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

**Search/Filter function**

```
product_names = Product.objects.filter(name__startswith=request.GET.get('query')).values('name', 'company')
```

**Output I have**

```
{"products": [{"name": "bla 2", "company": 3}, {"name": "bla 1", "company": 10}]}
```

**Output I want**

```
{"products": [{"name": "bla 2", "company": "apple"}, {"name": "bla 1", "company": "samsung"}]}
```

Comment: set `name` in `Company` model to primary key like this: `name = models.CharField(max_length=150, primary_key=True)`

Comment: I don't think setting the name as primary key would be smart, since products/companies can have equal names.

Comment: I would like to keep the default id as pk.

Comment: then try `from django.core import serializers` and then `print(serializers.serialize("json", [Product.objects.filter(name__startswith=request.GET.get('query'))]))`

Comment: I found the answer to my question! It was pretty easy: ```product_names = Product.objects.filter(name__startswith=request.GET.get('query')).values('name', 'company__name'))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what solved my problem:

```
product_names = Product.objects.filter(name__startswith=request.GET.get('query'))
.values('name', 'company__name'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Serializers here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Serializers allow you to specify the format that data is presented from your model, which sounds like what you want to achieve.

Comment: I found the answer to my question! It was pretty easy: ```product_names = Product.objects.filter(name__startswith=request.GET.get('query')).values('name', 'company__name'))``` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show `company` instead of `company__name` in your dictionary then you can use `F` object with `annotate` like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

product_names = Product.objects.filter(name__startswith=request.GET.get('query'))
.values('name').annotate(company=F('company__name')))
```

Comment: I found out there is even a shorter way :)

```.....values('id', 'name', company_name=F('company__name'))```

Comment: @dunkubok That doesn't work. And even if it did you would still be including `id` field into your dictionary which you didn't mentioned in your question :)

Comment: @dunkubok `.values('id', 'name', company_name=F('company__name'))` shows `company_name` not `company`